# Storing Location in array list if is changed onLocationChanged

Tags: android, arrays, list, maps

Hey Folks im trying now to store the location lat and long in array list and based on that want to draw a polylines,the idea would be if the user is moved it will draw a Polyline from the past latlng to the current latlng and so on.

Here is my code above im stuck right now to be able to store the location in the array list because if  I stored the location in first value when I call the array list.get(I+1) im getting IndexOutOFBounds error .

Any idea how  to write that on every change of location the location.latlng will be saved in array list and then the array list values will be displayed in the Polyline add.

Here is my code below :

Thanks !

```
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location){

            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();




            //is called only once
            lat.add(latitude);
            lng.add(longitude);


            //second coordinates
            lat.add(latitude);
            lng.add(longitude);


            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());

            try {
                List<Address> addresses =
                        geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                String result = addresses.get(0).getLocality()+":";
                result += addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                if (marker != null){
                    marker.remove();
                    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(result));
                    int i = 0;
                    Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                .clickable(true)
                                .add
                                        (       new LatLng(lat.get(i), lng.get(i)),
                                                new LatLng(lat.get(i + 1), lng.get(i + 1))
                                        ));

                        polyline.setEndCap(new RoundCap());
                        polyline.setWidth(POLYLINE_STROKE_WIDTH_PX);
                        polyline.setColor(COLOR_BLACK_ARGB);
                        polyline.setJointType(JointType.ROUND);
                        polyline.setColor(COLOR_BLACK_ARGB);

                        }
                    else
                    {
                        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(result));
                    int i = 0;
                    Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                            .clickable(true)
                            .add
                                    (       new LatLng(lat.get(i),lng.get(i)),
                                            new LatLng(lat.get(i+1),lng.get(i+1))
                                    ));

                    polyline.setEndCap(new RoundCap());
                    polyline.setWidth(POLYLINE_STROKE_WIDTH_PX);
                    polyline.setColor(COLOR_BLACK_ARGB);
                    polyline.setJointType(JointType.ROUND);
                    polyline.setColor(COLOR_BLACK_ARGB);

                    }


            } catch (IOException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem here is the code below: so you can track users location change with this code below :

```
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {


        ArrayList<Double> lastLat= new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double>lastLong= new ArrayList<>();
        int i = 0;


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location){

            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            lastLat.add(latitude);
            lastLong.add(longitude);


            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());

            try {
                List<Address> addresses =
                        geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                String result = addresses.get(0).getLocality()+":";
                result += addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                if (marker != null){
                    marker.remove();
                    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(result));

                    Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                .clickable(true)
                                .add
                                        (

                                                new LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                                                new LatLng(lastLat.get(i), lastLong.get(i))

                                        ));


                        polyline.setEndCap(new RoundCap());
                        polyline.setWidth(POLYLINE_STROKE_WIDTH_PX);
                        polyline.setColor(COLOR_BLACK_ARGB);
                        polyline.setJointType(JointType.ROUND);
                        polyline.setColor(COLOR_BLACK_ARGB);
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(result));
                    int i = 0;
                    Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                            .clickable(true)
                            .add
                                    (

                                            new LatLng(latitutde,longitude),
                                            new LatLng(lastLat.get(i),lastLong.get(i))



                                    ));
                    polyline.setEndCap(new RoundCap());
                    polyline.setWidth(POLYLINE_STROKE_WIDTH_PX);
                    polyline.setColor(COLOR_BLACK_ARGB);
                    polyline.setJointType(JointType.ROUND);
                    polyline.setColor(COLOR_BLACK_ARGB);

                        i++; }

                        } catch (IOException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
```